# Altering graphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays, includegraphics, handout

I have a Beamer frame with several items, each with a `\pause` before it. I want to display two figures, denoted A and B, as follows: Display A until the last `\pause`, then B. B should be at the same position as A was (i.e., overlaying it).
How can I do it? I would appreciate your help.

---

My current code displays `B.png` with the last `\pause` (as required). The problem is that `A.png` is never showed.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.55\textwidth}
        \pause
        \begin{itemize}
            \item i1
            \pause
            \item i2
            \pause
            \item i3
            \pause
            \item i4
            \pause
            \item i5
        \end{itemize}

        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics<1-4>[width=\textwidth]{A.png}%
            \includegraphics<5->[width=\textwidth]{B.png}%
        \end{center}
    \end{columns}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**Solution**, based on the accepted answer by @David:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \pause
        \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}[<+->]
                \item i1
                \item i2
                \item i3
                \item i4
                \item i5
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics<1-4>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
                \includegraphics<5->[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just deleting my answer and then reposting the same question again, still without providing a usable test case isn't that helpful.

Comment: 1. I followed your suggestion to stop editing the previous post; therefore, I opened a new one with the updated question and current code. Did you mean otherwise? 2. How can I provide testable code that includes figures? Thanks.

Comment: I have shown you how to provide usable examples in my answer. `example-image-a` is in tex distributions for that use. Your original question asked about making images appear after a few overlays. I answered that so you could simply have accepted that answer. This question is entirely different issue asking about the syntax for columns. The original question didn't even mention columns,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the correct syntax for columns, the previous answer of mine that you deleted works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item one
 \item item two
 \item item, the third
 \item 4\textsuperscript{th}
 \item 6
 \item seventh
 \item viii
 \end{itemize}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
 \includegraphics<1-7>[height=2cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
 \includegraphics<8-> [height=2cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By adding a `\pause` before the `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`, your suggestion solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to make only B appear in the Handout? (i.e., the output when using `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`.) It currently looks weird (side by side such that A is fully displayed and B is outside the frame).

Comment: No, but I'm told `\includegraphics<handout:0|1-7>[height=2cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}` or  `\includegraphics<1-7|beamer>` probably do what you want @keyboardAnt

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion worked like magic.